# reloading parent window using jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I've a Parent window which contains List of Product. By clicking one of the product it will  invoke a popUpWindow using jquery
code :

```
   $('a.modalDlg').click(function () {
     var urlPath= "/controllerName/actionName";
     var title="sample";
     var features="width = 400, height = 150,scrollbar=no";
     window.open(urlPath, $title, $fea);
   });
```

In the child window, after save Button is clicked -> the child window will close and parent window will be reloaded.

```
     window.opener.location.reload();
     window.close();
```

After this, the inserted value will be displayed in parent window.

But, instead of reloading the whole page(" window.opener.location.reload()") .
 Is there any possibility to  trigger the particular method in controller that contains List of Products??????
ex:

```
    public ActionResult DisplayProductDetails()
       {
          //some code
         return view();
       }
```

so, Because of this it will display the new inserted Product in Parent window & it would give better look instead of reloading entire page. (it is same like reloading the frames in HTML).

Pl help me out from this .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inject a JS method your **parent window's**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.updateWithNewData = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "url/to/your/partial/view/that/returns/new/data",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#dataContainer").append($("<div></div>").html(data));
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Call this from your **child window**

```
window.opener.updateWithNewData();
window.close();
```

OR

you may save the request to the server by providing a `JSON` object as parameter of `updateWithNewData` that is constructed from your pop-up window with your given data. And use the data passed on your **parent window**.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

In Chicld window call only close method after calling the Controller method
C# hasd the following code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayProductDetails()
{
     //some code
     return view("ViewName",ModelNameObject);
}
```

In JQuery Ajax call, make the event to trigger like below

```
$.ajax({
url:'UR URL to here'
dataType :'text json'
Method:Post
Success:function(data)
{
    $("#ParenetDivID").html(data);
}
});
```